# Why am I getting duplicate rows in Excel 2010 pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot, excel-2010

I'm working with a large table (800,000 rows) of data that I am summarizing in a pivot table (Excel 2010.)

I am trying to "pivot" based on the weight of the item rounded up to the nearest 0.1LB by adding a column that contains the formula =ROUNDUP(, 1).

For some reason, the pivot table is displaying duplicate row labels:

```
Weight 
Band        Pkg #   Processed
0.3         10,812  4,211
0.3         9,878   4,464    <<< Duplicate row label "0.3"
0.4         23,989  12,490
0.5         35,928  19,036
0.6         22,921  18,500
0.7         17,348  13,431
0.8         4,291   2,325
0.8         10,280  8,923    <<< Duplicate row label "0.8"
0.9         21,084  7,766
1           24,574  19,438
1.1         8,943   7,201
1.2         6,280   5,671
1.2         2,697   1,287    <<< Duplicate row label "1.2"
1.3         9,194   7,115
1.4         5,678   4,902
1.4         2,234   1,225    <<< Duplicate row label "1.4"
1.5         7,631   5,926
```

Looking at the auto-filter drop-down on the raw column of data does NOT show duplicate values, but the filter on the pivot table does.

Thinking that the ROUND() formula might be the problem, I replaced the formulas with values to simplify things -- but the dupes still remain.

Any ideas on why this might be occurring?

Comment: Would need to see some raw data to try and reproduce. but any time you're playing with pivots rebuild it in a new sheet/tab.  I've found some level of caching seems to occur.  So if you started off w/o rounding, the cached values may be stored with the unrounded values.  if you then added the rounding, it may still be using that cached values somehow.  If you truly have a column within the pivot table where the round has and create the pivot after this, I don't think you'll get the duplicates.  Be interested to know if this solves the issue...

Comment: I tried your idea, but it made no difference.  Just for grins, I suffixed the contents of the column with an alpha string (i.e. "0.5" changed to "0.5 LB") and wouldn't you know the dupes disappeared! I'm thinking that Excel may have a small bug using numerics -- even if text -- as row labels. Maybe a storage/rounding issue?

Comment: so to understand your question more clearly, when you say duplicate row label -> you have added the field "Weight Band" to the Row section of your pivot table and it shows it more than once? Have you checked if the values in that column have whitespace around them (if text)? Have you checked, if not text, that they are truly the same number and not just displayed as the same number (e.g. 1.47 and 1.48 both being displayed as 1.5)?

Comment: Yes, you understood the problem. And, yes, they are the same number.  The weight band number was created by rounding (up) the weight of each piece to the next tenth of a pound, so every band should have been, by definition, 1 digit right of the decimal. Maybe Excel was "hiding" some precision that I could not see, but what is stranger is that the autofilter on the main data page did not show any duplicates in the raw data. The filter on the pivot summary did show duplicates -- even though it is by definition a summary of the raw data. By adding a character suffix was a work-around.

Comment: so i finally got round to looking into this. I am unable to replicate the issue with the data posted so that does suggest it was something to do with decimal places, which is strange as the ROUND should have got rid of this. Wrapping it in a TRUNC() function should test that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a alphanumeric suffix to the numeric labels seems to have gotten around the issue.  For example, instead of the row labels looking like:

```
My Column
"0.1"
"0.2"
"0.3"
"0.4"
...
```

They now look like this:

```
My Column
"0.1 lb"
"0.2 lb"
"0.3 lb"
"0.4 lb"
...
```

and the duplicate labels in the pivot table have disappeared.

Maybe Excel was interpreting the labels as numbers and having rounding issues?

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve the issue is to use Text to Columns feature in the Data Ribbon to FORCE excel to change all the cell values to text (or whatever form you want).  This means you don't have to add the LB suffix.

Still this shuold nto be necessarry. This appears to be an Excel Bug!  I ahve had the same problem and realised that even trying to change the format of the data to text any other way fails.  DOn'r know why.  The only way that works, trying to change tio to text is to use Text to Columns function.